# Адаптивная вёрстка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

вот код:

```css
#intouch {
  font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold, bold;
  width: 17%;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid #be0000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #be0000;
  font-size: 300%;
  color: #be0000;
}

#options {
  background: #be0000;
  font-size: 190%;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 83%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  padding-top: 1.6%;
}

.option {
  padding-left: 7%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="intouch">На связи</div>
  <div id="options">
    <span class="option">Регистрация</span>
    <span class="option">Вход</span>
    <span class="option">Пожертвования</span>
    <span class="option">Контакты</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Дело в том что на устройствах с разным разрешением это выводится криво. Как решить этот вопрос без @media?

Comment: Почему решили без медиа запросов (@media)?

Comment: Мы на курсах ещё их не проходили

Comment: Адаптацию под верстку отлично делают меди запроса и разобраться в них совсем не сложно. Это вам на курсах поставили такую задачу, без @media?

Comment: Используйте проценты, если медиа пока нельзя. Здесь принято выкладывать учебные задачи с попытками решений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `flex`, точнее `flex-flow: row wrap;` позволит переносить контент если не будет вмещаться. При этом можно задавать ширину как в процентах (как у Вас) так и фикс, если не вместится на опр. разрешении - блоки будут перестраиваться друг под другом:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#intouch {
  font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold, bold;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid #be0000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #be0000;
  color: #be0000;
  font-size: 20px;
  
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

#options {
  background: #be0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  padding-top: 1.6%;
  padding-bottom: 1.6%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-shrink:0;
  
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div id="intouch">На связи</div>
  <div id="options">
    <span class="option">Регистрация</span>
    <span class="option">Вход</span>
    <span class="option">Пожертвования</span>
    <span class="option">Контакты</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Еще если без медиазапросов (`@media`), то, **как вариант**, использовать размер шрифта в `vw` или `vh`, а то проценты как-то не особо хорошо работают:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#intouch {
  font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold, bold;
  width: 17%;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid #be0000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #be0000;
  color: #be0000;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

#options {
  background: #be0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 83%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  padding-top: 1.6%;
  
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.option {
  padding-left: 7%;
}
```

```html
<div id="intouch">На связи</div>
<div id="options">
  <span class="option">Регистрация</span>
  <span class="option">Вход</span>
  <span class="option">Пожертвования</span>
  <span class="option">Контакты</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте внутренние паддинги для #intouch и #options. Если `.option { display: inline-block}`, то лучше писать `.option:not(:last-child){padding-right: 7%}` А вообще проценты действительно плохо работают, как сказали выше